# Авторизация через сайт WordPress

Tags: java, android, wordpress

У меня есть сайт на WordPress и мне нужно реализовать авторизацию в андроид приложении через этот сайт. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

рекомендую посмотреть на этот плагин от wordpress

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

это расширенная возможность авторизации используя REST JSON API

так же заглянуть сюда:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-oauth-10a-authentication--cms-24797
- https://github.com/Automattic/android-wordpress-com-rest/blob/master/WordPressComRest/src/main/java/com/wordpress/rest/Oauth.java